# Is there a way to remove the background from a label?

Tags: python, tkinter

Is there a way to remove the white background behind the username label? I know how to change the color of it, but how do I remove it all together.

here's my code below:

```py
label = tk.Label(text="HELLO, I'M AIDER", font=("Monument Extended", 36), fg="white", borderwidth=0, relief="flat")
label.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor='center')
```

[image]

I'm expecting a transparent background with the words "Hello, I'm Aider"

Comment: Tkinter widgets are opaque rectangles.  Transparency is not an option.

Comment: What white background?  You have white foreground with black background.

Comment: If you want transparency because you have a background image, you can use a single `tkinter` canvas using `create_text`

Comment: You can set the background color to the same as the widget below it.

Answer (score 1):

Transparent backgrounds for labels aren’t supported in Tkinter. A workaround is to make a particular colour transparent using the wm_attribute() function of the root instance. Example code:

```
root.wm_attributes('-transparentcolor','black')
```

This will make the black colour transparent.

Another method, as @TheLizzard suggested, is to use a Canvas. Example code:

```
…

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Example App")

canvas = tk.Canvas(root, height=300, width=1000)
canvas.pack()

bg_img = tk.PhotoImage(file="blue.png")
bg_label = canvas.create_image((0,0), image=bg_img, anchor=tk.N+tk.W)

your_text = canvas.create_text((POSITION_X, POSITION_Y), text="Sample Text", font="Arial 50 bold", fill="#ffffff")

root.mainloop()
```

Here ‘blue.png’ is an image file with a solid blue colour.